# Uninitialized constant error on has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a question about active-record association in Rails.
I'm developing three active-record model: Team, Teamuser, users, testing on "has_many through" association.
basically, I just want to be able to call team.users and user.teams.

here are my model definitions

```
  team.rb
  #######
  class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :teamusers, :foreign_key => :team_id
    has_many :users, :through => :teamusers

  end
```

and

```
  teamuser.rb
  ###########
  class Teamuser < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :teams  
    belongs_to :users   

  end
```

then

```
  user.rb
  ########
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :teamusers, :foreign_key => :user_id
    has_many :teams, :through => :teamusers

  end
```

every time I try this

team.users

it returns me an error saying "uninitialized constant Team::Users".

what might I be wrong he?
any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Teamuser should be:

```
class Teamuser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```